# HttpWebRequest GetResponse confused by 100 continue codes

Tags: c#, .net, http, networking, .net-core

The below code snippet sends a request to a URL, then gets the response.

I have watched its behaviour in Wireshark. In Wireshark, I see the original `POST` request going out, and then I see two responses coming back.
The first is a `"100 Continue"` response. The second is a `"200 OK"` response.
Submitting this request in a web browser results in exactly the same responses, and browsers correctly identify this as an "OK" response.

If I understand correctly, the `"100 Continue"` response is supposed to be handled by `.net` behind the scenes, and so my "lResponse" variable should capture the "200 OK". However, instead `lWebRequest.GetResponse( )` throws an error complaining about getting a `"100 Continue"` response.

I have tried setting **`Expect100Continue`** on the **`ServicePointManager`** to both true and false, and I have tried increasing the continue timeout. Neither made any difference.

```cs
HttpWebRequest lWebRequest = ( HttpWebRequest ) WebRequest.Create( "REMOVED" );
lWebRequest.Method = "POST";
lWebRequest.ContentLength = lsPost.Length;
lWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
lWebRequest.Host = "REMOVED";
lWebRequest.Referer = "REMOVED";

StreamWriter lStreamWriter = null;

try
{
    lStreamWriter = new StreamWriter( lWebRequest.GetRequestStream( ) );
    lStreamWriter.Write( lsPost );
}
catch ( Exception lError )
{
    Console.WriteLine( lError.Message );
    return;
}
finally
{
    lStreamWriter.Close( );
}

HttpWebResponse lResponse = null;

try
{
    lResponse = ( HttpWebResponse ) lWebRequest.GetResponse( );
}
catch ( Exception lError )
{
    Console.WriteLine( lError.Message );
    return;
}

String lsResult = "";

using ( StreamReader lStreamReader = new StreamReader( lResponse.GetResponseStream( ) ) )
{
    lsResult = lStreamReader.ReadToEnd( );

    lStreamReader.Close( );
}
Console.WriteLine( lsResult );
```

Comment: Set it directly on the `WebRequest`: `lWebRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;` right after you create it.

Comment: Tried that already. No difference.

Comment: Yep, tried precisely that. The server always seems to respond in two parts in any case. Isn't there a way of receiving the second part of the response?

Comment: Out of curiosity, I moved the project from .net Core 2.1 to the full .net Framework. Suddenly, I see that the Expect header is being set properly, and I no longer hit that exception. So it looks like this is a .net Core specific issue. Luckily I'm not that tied to .net Core.

Comment: WELL, this is an information that you should have inserted as the first line of your question **and** in its tags. The tag is now `.net`, not `.net-core.` There are a number of differences from the .Net FrameWork and .Net Core. The main difference, in this case, is that **.Net Core does not support ServicePointManager settings**. These can be set just for compatibility (code transfer).

Comment: I stupidly imagined they were identical in areas of common functuality. Thanks for the info.